# Symfony 3 Forms - How to programmatically set form theme

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I've trying to write a generic admin controller system which you configure with the entity type and related form and it generates the CRUD forms automatically - its working fine, the only wrinkle is with field which are Master->Detail types - i.e. in Doctrine, they'd be the @OnetoMany doctrine mappings.

Again, they work at the moment, but the form rendering is ugly to say the least. What I want to do is to detect these properties and automatically apply a tabular form template for the detail records.

To give an example, say the page was editing a Customer entity and the detail were the domain names that they had bought, along with a checkbox for whether the domain was in use or not.

The main form is themed using "bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout".

Currently the domains are displayed, but over two lines, what I want is a single line per domain, with the textbox for domain name followed by a checkbox for whether its in use.

I've tried as per the docs, to set the theme setting of property of the form, but that appears to do nothing.

i.e. {% form_theme form.domains 'admin/instance/domains_form.html.twig' %}

But it has no effect on the rendering of the list of domains, nor the prototype which is used to add a new domain to the list.

Any pointers / suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm using Symfony 3.4 btw.

Steve.

p.s. the twig template which displays the form is currently:

```
{% form_theme form.domains 'admin/instance/domains_form.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}

{{ form_widget(form) }}
```